# Haskell and Rank-N polymorphism

Tags: haskell, types

What's exactly wrong about the following hypothetical Haskell code?  When I compile it in my brain, it should output "1".

```
foo :: forall a. forall b. forall c. (a -> b) -> c -> Integer -> b
foo f x n = if n > 0 then f True else f x

bar :: forall a. a -> Integer
bar x = 1

main = do
     putStrLn (show (foo bar 1 2))
```

GHC complains:

```
$ ghc -XRankNTypes -XScopedTypeVariables poly.hs 

poly.hs:2:28:
     Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `Bool'
       `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for `foo' at poly.hs:1:14
     In the first argument of `f', namely `True'
     In the expression: f True
     In the expression: if n > 0 then f True else f x

poly.hs:2:40:
     Couldn't match expected type `Bool' against inferred type `c'
       `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
            the type signature for `foo' at poly.hs:1:34
     In the first argument of `f', namely `x'
     In the expression: f x
     In the expression: if n > 0 then f True else f x
```

What does that mean?  Isn't it valid Rank-N polymorphism?
(Disclaimer: I'm absolutely not a Haskell programmer, but OCaml doesn't support such explicit type signatures.)

Comment: ah the brain. my favourite compiler of all :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not actually using rank-N polymorphism in your code.

```
foo :: forall a. forall b. forall c. (a -> b) -> c -> Integer -> b
```

This is an ordinary rank-1 type. It reads: forall a,b and c this function can take a function of type `a -> b`, a value of type `c` and an `Integer` and return a value of type `b`. So it says that it can take a function of type `Bool -> Integer` or a function of type `Integer -> Integer`. It does **not** say that the function has to be polymorphic in its argument. To say that, you need to use:

```
foo :: forall b. forall c. (forall a. a -> b) -> c -> Integer -> b
```

Now you're saying that the type of the function needs to be `forall a. a -> b`, where `b` is fixed, but `a` is a newly introduced variable, so the function needs to be polymorphic in its argument.

Comment: Are there any interesting occupants of the type forall a. a -> b? The only one that springs to mind is a function which takes an argument but doesn't use it at all: f x = 12 for example, like his function bar above.

Comment: @chrisdb: ... which happens to be the result of `const 12`. And `const` has found a few applications.

Comment: @delnan: ...I can see it might be useful in a few circumstances (just like id is useful). But it doesn't seem particularly _interesting_, in the same way that id isn't interesting even though it is useful sometimes.

Comment: I guess S and K are very important in the implementation of Haskell, so I probably shouldn't insult const even if it seems pretty boring...

Comment: loved this explanation

Comment: I did not understand rank-N polymorphism until I read this sentence: "Now you're saying that the type of the function needs to be `forall a. a -> b,` where `b` is fixed, but `a` is a newly introduced variable, so the function needs to be polymorphic in its argument." _The function needs to be polymorphic in its argument._ YES! I finally get it. I actually jumped around for a moment like a kid.